# how to nicely indent when the \t is incorrect.

Tags: java, indentation

I'm trying to have the indentation correct. In the code below, the s2 comes from a database and output to the console (System.out.println). In fact, S2 is a list of objects and the s2 is the toString with the indentation. But for simplicity issues, consider the following code:

```
public class TestIndent
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String s1 = "CASE NUM\tTYPE\tREF DATE\tAMOUNT";
        String s2 = "9157120183\tPPAQ\t*** REF DATE NOT EXISTS! ***\t$95.00";       

        System.out.println(s1);
        System.out.println(s2);
    }
}
```

The output for this will be:

```
CASE NUM    TYPE    REF DATE    AMOUNT
9157120183  PPAQ    *** REF DATE NOT EXISTS! ***    $95.00
```

My desire is to have it indent correctly like this:

```
CASE NUM    TYPE    REF DATE                        AMOUNT
9157120183  PPAQ    *** REF DATE NOT EXISTS! ***    $95.00
```

You will note that the 'AMOUNT' is right on top of the number (which is the correct place). 
So just before I'm writing any class that will indent it based on the MAX length of a String, I was wondering if anything already exists for this problem.

Comment: You would need to go through all your rows and find out the longest length for each field. Then set the amount of space between headers based on those lengths.

Comment: "*** REF DATE NOT EXISTS! ***" is longer than "REF DATE\t". Firstly you would need to know how many spaces there are in your systems tab character, then work out how many tabs you need to balance the longest value for the column. Or view in something that lines things up for you and just separate with commas.

Comment: `\t` just spaces over to the next column multiple of 8. Any text longer than 8 will cause this problem. As @SotiriosDelimanolis mentioned, add additional spaces to your titles (after the text part but before the tab) to make sure the title takes up as much space as the longest value for the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tab character is a single character that will render differently in different environments so it is inherently hard to use - what looks nice on your console may look fine on mine, or poo on Lee Meador's who has 8 character wide tabs.

You could use Sotirios's suggestion by creating a function to pad you headers with spaces - as you can trust spaces. Of course if your console is not using a fixed width font you can not rely on this either - but it will be better.

You could also use javas inbuilt [String formatting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) to reduce the need for manual calculation if you know how wide you want to display your columns, but it will truncate long values, e.g:

```
System.out.printf("%-10.10s  %-6.6s %-30.30s %-10.10s%n", "CASE NUM", "TYPE", "REF DATE", "AMOUNT");
System.out.printf("%-10.10s  %-6.6s %-30.30s %-10.10s%n", "9157120183", "PPAQ", "*** REF DATE NOT EXISTS! ***", "$95.00");
```

Or you could leave your output tab separated or comma separated and write it to a file and let a program designed for rendering these things deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.println()`'s tab behavior depends on the underlying OS.  If you want to have more control (especially if your OS does not offer any of it), you better replace them with spaces inside the Java program according to some algorightm (fixed spaced tabs, or variably spaced tabs).

Another alternative is that you keep tabs as they are in the output, but redirecting it to a file.  Then open the file whith a tool that does allow control on tab size.  This depends on OS, of course.